# ASSERT implementation for Coverity test?

Tags: c, assert, coverity

In our project, ASSERT is defined:

```
#define ASSERT(condition, severity)         bsp_assert(condition, severity)
```

Then in bsp_assert:

```
void bsp_assert(uint8_t condition, uint8_t severity)
{
  if(severity == SEVERITY_HIGH)
  {
    ll_sys_assert(condition);
  }
}
```

When we run Coverity analysis with agression High, we got thousands of errors related to this assert, like this:

```
2. var_compare_op Comparing ptr_chnl_clsfction to null implies that ptr_chnl_clsfction might be null.
       ASSERT(NULL != ptr_chnl_clsfction , SEVERITY_HIGH);

CID 442026: (#1 of 1): Dereference after null check (FORWARD_NULL)
5. var_deref_op Dereferencing null pointer ptr_chnl_clsfction.
           ptr_chnl_clsfction[byte_iter] = 0x00;
```

I tried to comment bsp_assert, like this:

```
#define ASSERT(condition, severity)  /*We don't use assert*/
```

Now I don't have any more the issue, but I guess it's not the purpose of assert.

How can I get rid of this issue ?

Thanks.

Comment: The `bsp_assert` does not terminate the program and let's it run further even if the condition is not met. One if these conditions is that the `ptr_chnl_clsfction` pointer isn't `NULL`. But if it is `NULL`, the program should not continue as later on it is being dereferenced. This is what Coverity is trying to tell you.

Comment: Thanks, I get the point of Coverity, the fact is that Coverity doesn't care what is inside `bsp_assert`, it only care what is inside ASSERT. In our implementation,  in `ll_sys_assert` will be an infinite loop `while(1)`. I don't know how should I implement ASSERT to avoid these error from Coverity.

Comment: Is `ll_sys_assert` implementation visible to Coverity? If it is, but it still can't infer it, then I guess it's a false positive here and should be suppressed. Alternatively you can model it to let Coverity know it is a "kill path" as documented here: https://community.synopsys.com/s/article/How-to-write-a-function-model-to-eliminate-a-false-positive-in-a-C-applilcation

Comment: Yes, it is, but Coverity doesn't care what inside `ll_sys_assert`, it only care about `ASSERT`.

Comment: See update to my previous comment. FWIW, it should "care" what ASSERT is expanding into.. Not sure why you think it doesn't or why it doesn't  if you are right

Comment: Does Coverity look at the `bsp_assert()` function definition at all? Is `ll_sys_assert()` declared with the `_Noreturn` specifier?

Comment: Please add the implementation of `ll_sys_assert` to the question.  Its exact definition is important to understanding why the tool is behaving the way it is.

Answer (score 1):

THis is how `FORWARD_NULL` is reported in Coveritys:

> In Coverity, FORWARD_NULL reports defects when there are enough
> evidences to be sure the null access will (can) happen.
>
> first, a null assignment, or a comparison with null will give Coverity
> an evidence to believe the variable could be null.
>
> second, a de-reference of that variable.
>
> When above 2 events happen in the same analysis path, then Coverity
> will report FORWARD_NULL on the second event

If `ptr_chnl_clsfction`  is NULL

Dereferencing will result in crash

```
ptr_chnl_clsfction[byte_iter] = 0x00
```

Comment: I understand how `FORWARD_NULL` works, I just don't know how should I implement ASSERT to avoid this error, in our current implementation, we use a `while(1)` loop, but Coverity doesn't seem like it. Or should I disable FORWARD_NULL checker ?

Comment: IDK how your code looks like, Is it possible that deference can happen AND this pointer is NULL?